# Double substituting Unix variable

Tags: shell, unix

I'm trying to get a value of the variable by double substituting inside the string as follows

```
i=1
df1 ='date_col'

X='value of the string is $df$i'
```

But getting invalid substitution error

I need the output as follows

```
echo $X 
value of the string is date_col
```

Comment: What shell are you using?

Comment: What you want is called "indirect expansion". There are better ways to do it in extended shells such as bash, ksh, or zsh; the only approaches available with `/bin/sh` [have security issues](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048).

Comment: For an extensive discussion, see [BashFAQ #6](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006).

Comment: (also, if you're using an extended shell, you have arrays; `declare -a df=( [1]=date_col )` and then you can refer to `${df[1]}`; if the keys can be arbitrary strings instead of just numeric, then in bash one would use `declare -A` instead)

Comment: I'm using bash shell